# Preprocessing without compiling with etoolbox

Tags: compiling, etoolbox

I want to know if it is possible to do preprocessing without compiling with the `etoolbox` package.  Basically, I want to do the following.  Given a file of the following format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\providebool{pre}
\setbool{pre}{true}

\begin{document}
This line is always there.

\ifbool{pre}{
  This line is there if \texttt{pre}.
}{
  This line is here if \texttt{\tilde pre}.
}


\end{document}
```

I want to know if there is a way of compiling it with so that I get as output a file containing the following text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\providebool{pre}
\setbool{pre}{true}

\begin{document}
This line is always there.

This line is there if \texttt{pre}.


\end{document}
```

A similar feature is provided by the `cleveref` package via its `poorman` option, but it just automatically produces a `sed` script to modify the original file.  If there is a way to achieve even that (i.e., producing automatically a `sed` script which can be run on the original file to get the required output) I'll be glad of learn about that too.

EDIT: clarification in response to @egreg:  I actually want to get the preprocessed source file at the end of the compilation, rather than just the correctly conditionally compiled pdf output.  For example, compiling the first example above with `pdflatex`  will produce a `pdf` output that is exactly the same as that produced by compiling the second example.  However, what I want at the end of the compilation is not just the right `pdf` output, but also a source file in which the rejected branches of the `ifbool` have been completely removed.

My use case is that I have a source file that is written to produce two different `pdf` outputs for two different recipients based on a flag (like the flag `pre` above).  However, one of the outputs needs to be sent to a recipient who also requires the TeX source.  I do not want this recipient to see the conditionals I put in to customize the output for them.

Comment: If you construct your document using `This line is always there. \ifpre This line is there if \texttt{pre}.\else This line is here if \texttt{not pre}\fi` then you can call the document from the command line using `pdflatex \newif\pre\pretrue \input{file.tex}` where you set `\pretrue` or `\prefalse` as needed. Then you don't need [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).

Comment: Do you want to get a *file* or only to do conditional compilation?

Comment: @egreg: I actually want the TeX source.  `etoolbox` already produces the right conditional pdf output on compilation. My use case is that I need to share the source file as well as the output, but I do not want the recipient to see the conditionals I put in place to customize the output for them.

Comment: Then TeX is *not* the right tool to use.

Comment: @egreg: In fact, in my use case, TeX is the _only_ tool I _can_ use (any other tool would be hopelessly insufficient).  Thanks for the response anyway.  It does look like there is no readily available tool capable of achieving what I want to do.  I had my hopes up just because `cleveref` (somewhat) surprisingly did have a similar feature  which allowed me to remove instances of its use.

Comment: What about `docstrip`?

Comment: ...or LuaTeX, which obviously could do it (maybe called as `texlua`, so that it's just a lua interpreter)?

Answer (score 4):

This will create a cleaned source file (but not a pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\providebool{pre}
%\setbool{pre}{true}
\setbool{pre}{false}
\begin{document}
\newoutputstream{preproc}
\openoutputfile{preproc}{preproc}
%
\addtostream{preproc}{\protect\documentclass{article}}
\addtostream{preproc}{\protect\begin{document}}
\addtostream{preproc}{This line is always there.\par}
\ifbool{pre}{
\addtostream{preproc}{  This line is there if \texttt{pre}.}
}{
\addtostream{preproc}{  This line is here if \texttt{\textasciitilde pre}.}
}
\addtostream{preproc}{\protect\end{document}}
\closeoutputstream{preproc}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Following file `main.tex` provides preprocessed output files 
`output.tex` and `output.pdf` with the command 
`pdflatex --jobname=output main`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{output}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{preproc}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\providebool{pre}
\setbool{pre}{true}
%\setbool{pre}{false}
\begin{document}
\newoutputstream{preproc}
\openoutputfile{preproc}{preproc}
%
%\addtostream{preproc}{\protect\documentclass{article}}
%\addtostream{preproc}{\protect\begin{document}}
\addtostream{preproc}{This line is always there.\par}
\ifbool{pre}{
\addtostream{preproc}{  This line is there if \texttt{pre}.}
}{
\addtostream{preproc}{  This line is here if \texttt{\textasciitilde pre}.}
}
%\addtostream{preproc}{\protect\end{document}}
\closeoutputstream{preproc}
\input{preproc}
\end{document}
```